# Which character, from any script, most resembles a spool of thread / drum of cable?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a symbol that could be used to represent a drum of cable. For example, I have a loose reel of cable denoted by ෧, a box of cable denoted by ◻ and currently a drum represented by .
For reference, a cable drum looks like this:

[image]

This symbol  for the drum is an emoji, and I would like something similar in shape but as plain text. For example, like capital pi but also with a bottom bar. A tall rectangle with longer top and bottom lines.
This will be used to concisely and visually display my stock range on a cable price list.

I have played with lined rectangles, but cannot find the right one. ⌸
Something more suitable would be like this Ⅱ (roman "2") but with straighter lines. In my document, with this symbol, it is quite obvious and is read as a "2".

I have looked through thousands of unicode symbols across many websites but cannot find a language with such box-like scripts, or any special characters with such a shape.

Many thanks in advance, if you have any ideas!

Comment: Sorry but I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a question about the English language.

Comment: This does seem like a fun and well researched question, but unfortunately I don't know any other sites where it might be on-topic. A variation on this question might be on topic somewhere (eg how to get a spool symbol in a TeX document—probably on topic on TeX/LaTeX SE).

Comment: You could try Indian languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_scripts_of_the_Republic_of_India

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "but with straighter lines" when referring to `Ⅱ`.  Do you mean shorter lines, so it's more "squat"?

Comment: lower case pi (π) sometimes has legs that curl outwards, although it depends on the font.